# Mapdeck Package in R - add_grid Does Not Appear to Render Anything

Tags: r, geospatial, deck.gl, mapdeck

**Problem:**

The `add_grid` function in the R `mapdeck` package is very exciting.  However, following the [CRAN documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapdeck/mapdeck.pdf), I cannot seem to get any data to actually plot on the returned map.

In other words, the map returns, but no data is plotted.  Is this a known bug?

**Code:**

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mapdeck)

# - Enter mapdeck key ... Note that it is user-specific
key <- rstudioapi::askForPassword() 

# - Read Example Data Set
df <- read.csv(paste0(
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber-common/deck.gl-data/master/',
  'examples/3d-heatmap/heatmap-data.csv'
))

# - Plot Data ... Note how the map returns, but not the data
mapdeck( token = key, style = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9', pitch = 45 ) %>%
  add_grid(
    data = df
    , lat = "lat"
    , lon = "lng"
    , cell_size = 5000
    , elevation_scale = 50
    , layer_id = "grid_layer"
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

**Output:**

[image: Map Output - Lacking Data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily a 'bug' inside `mapdeck` itself, but more the way `mapdeck` communicates with `RStudio`. There are conflicts between the different javascript versions they use.

If you open the plot in a browser (by pressing the **show in new window** button in Rstudio) you should get your plot.

[image]

I've got this issue [logged](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues/18), but don't know the way forward yet.

Comment: Great package and great work - Thanks for the quick response!  The workaround works great - Hopefully the RStudio Team help with this in the future.