# Why does spplot take so much time for multiple panels

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, shapefile, r-sp

I am plotting multiple shapefiles using spplot. Here's a data to construct that

```
library(raster)
library(randomcoloR)

my.shp <- getData('GADM', country = 'BRA', level = 2)
my.shp$ID<- 1:nrow(my.shp)
```

My data consists of a variable `X` for 10 years as shown where each column is a year

```
df <- matrix(sample(100:5000, 55040, replace = T), nrow = 5504, ncol = 10)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:nrow(my.shp), df)

my.dat <- merge(my.shp, df, by = "ID")

variable.names <- paste0("X",1:10)

spplot(my.dat, rev(variable.names), col = NA, at = seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 500), 
          col.regions = distinctColorPalette(length(seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 500))),
          main = list(label = "TEST"))
```

My problem is this plot takes so much time (around an hour) to get plotted and was wondering if there is something inherently wrong in the code itself that it is taking too long to plot. My laptop has a 32 GB RAM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you willing/able to switch to `sf` instead of `sp`?

The sf plot function is considerably faster than spplot, although the layout differs a bit.

```
library(sf)
my.dat_sf <- st_as_sf(my.dat)
plot(my.dat_sf[rev(variable.names)], max.plot=10, breaks=c(seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 500),5000),
     pal = distinctColorPalette(length(seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 500))),
     main = "TEST", border=NA, key.pos=4)
```

Additionally, you could try to simplify the polygon with `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()` for Spatial*-objects or `sf::st_simplify()` for SimpleFeatures, which lets you reduce the object size by quite a bit, depending on the given `dTolerance`. Thus plotting, will also be faster with simplified polygons.

The original SpatialPolygon:

```
format(object.size(my.dat_sf), units="Kb")
```

> "25599.2 Kb"

and a simplified SimpleFeature:

```
dat_sf_simple <- st_transform(my.dat_sf, crs = 3035)
dat_sf_simple <- st_simplify(dat_sf_simple, dTolerance = 1000, preserveTopology = T)
dat_sf_simple <- st_transform(dat_sf_simple, crs = 4326)
format(object.size(dat_sf_simple), units="Kb")
```

> "7864.2 Kb"

Plot the simplified SimpleFeature, which takes about 1 minute on my machine with 8GB RAM.

```
plot(dat_sf_simple[rev(variable.names)], max.plot=10, breaks=c(seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 500),5000),
     pal = distinctColorPalette(length(seq(from = 100, to = 5000, by = 500))),
     main = "TEST", border=NA, key.pos=4)
```

You could also try out with `ggplot2`, but I am pretty sure the most performant solution will be the sf plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat_sf_simple_gg <- dat_sf_simple %>% 
  dplyr::select(rev(variable.names), geometry) %>% 
  gather(VAR, SID, -geometry)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = dat_sf_simple_gg, aes(fill=SID)) + 
  facet_wrap(~VAR, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Okay. I have two follow up questions: my solution allows me to have a common legend across all the maps. How do I insert a common legend in your solution? Second If I want to add the state boundary on top, in my solution I can just do `latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(my.boundary, lwd = 0.05))`. How does that work in your case?

Comment: To see the state boundaries, remove `border=NA`. And to add a legend, add `key.pos=4` in the plot call.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was if I want to add another polygon on top of this map, how do I do it. Doing border = NA will only remove the current boundary of the municipalities on this

Comment: Could you include the call to `latticeExtra::layer` in your example. I am not able to make that plot and therefore I dont really know hwo the result should look like. But sf plot also takes the argument `add`. But I dont really know how it will add to the plot, if the plot has "facets" when plotting multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't compared this plot to your `spplot` because I don't want to spend an hour waiting for it.

Instead I'm proposing to use `library(mapdeck)` to plot an interactive map, which takes a matter of seconds.

Two things to note

1. You need a Mapbox Access token
2. You need to convert the `sp` object to `sf`

```r
library(raster)

my.shp <- getData('GADM', country = 'BRA', level = 2)
my.shp$ID <- 1:nrow(my.shp)

df <- matrix(sample(100:5000, 55040, replace = T), nrow = 5504, ncol = 10)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:nrow(my.shp), df)

my.dat <- merge(my.shp, df, by = "ID")


library(sf)
sf <- sf::st_as_sf( my.dat )

library(mapdeck)

set_token( "YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN" )

mapdeck() %>% 
  add_sf(
    data = sf
    , fill_colour = "GID_2"
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks though it looks like a good alternative, I cannot unfortunately award my bounty since I am interested in the solution to my exact problem. I will do use your approach for other stuff. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Interestingly, I see a blank page using this approach. Any reason why that would be the cause? I tried using both the public as well as private token

Comment: Try opening it in a browser.  See here too https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/issues.html

Comment: Okay thanks. Looks like I can only open rstudio on a web browser in linux. I only know how to work on windows. Thanks anyway

Comment: The browser should open no matter which platform you're on.

Comment: "RStudio is available in open source and commercial editions and runs on the desktop (Windows, Mac, and Linux) or in a browser connected to RStudio Server or RStudio Server Pro (Debian/Ubuntu, RedHat/CentOS, and SUSE Linux)."..so does it mean R studio server is not available for windows?

Comment: I don't mean open RStudio in a browser, I mean open the plot in a browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470812/5977215